# How to give a boolean indicator to React useEffect to track if it's being used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a React UseEffect, and I want to be able to set an indicator `isEffectUsed` if to track if the effect has happened and data is fetched from an api.

```js
export const useApi= (ApiUrl, someSettings) => {

  const [output, setOutput] = useState(null);
  let isEffectUsed= false; // "false" is pending effect, "true" is effect occurred

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const a = fetch(ApiUrl, {
        method: "post", 
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(someSettings)})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data=>setOutput(data))
      .then(()=>{output==null ? isEffectUsed=false : isEffectUsed=true});

  }, [someSettings]);

  return {output: output, isEffectUsed: isEffectUsed};
}
```

I'm getting `isEffectUsed` as `false` whether the effect has been used or not. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: `then(()=>{output==null` output will not have changed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the last `.then()` doesn't seem to be valid because `.then(data=>setOutput(data))` doesn't quite return a promise.

So to be able to chain the last `.then()` you should return a `Promise.resolve` from the previous `.then()` like this

```js
.then((data) => Promise.resolve(setOutput(data)))
```

Next, consider setting `isEffectUsed` to a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) as opposed to a plain variable, that way you can manage the different values across multiple states

```js
export const useApi= (ApiUrl, someSettings) => {

const [output, setOutput] = useState(null);
const isEffectUsed = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(ApiUrl, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(someSettings),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => Promise.resolve(setOutput(data)))
    .then(() => {
      // This basically resets isEffectUsed only if output is set
      output && isEffectUsed.current=true;
    });
}, [someSettings]);
 

  return {output: output, isEffectUsed: isEffectUsed.current };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `useRef` or `useState` to change the value of `isEffectUsed`.

if you choose `useRef` then.

```
export const useApi= (ApiUrl, someSettings) => {

  const [output, setOutput] = useState(null);
  let isEffectUsed= useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const a = fetch(ApiUrl, {
        method: "post", 
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(someSettings)})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data=> {
        if(data) {
            setOutput(data)
            isEffectUsed.current=true;
        }
      })

  }, [someSettings]);

  return {output: output, isEffectUsed: isEffectUsed.current};
}
```

And here is the example using `useState`:

```
export const useApi= (ApiUrl, someSettings) => {

  const [output, setOutput] = useState(null);
  let [isEffectUsed, setIsEffectUsed]= useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const a = fetch(ApiUrl, {
        method: "post", 
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(someSettings)})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data=> {
        if(data) {
            setOutput(data)
            setIsEffectUsed(true);
        }
      })

  }, [someSettings]);

  return {output: output, isEffectUsed: isEffectUsed};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use an useState hook to set whether effect has changed or not. This way you give react a reference to keep track and update isEffectUsed accordingly.